# Combine different grViz into a single plot

Tags: r, diagram, htmlwidgets

I would like to combine different `DiagrammeR` plots into a single figure. The plots are generated as the following example:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
pDia <- grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {

  # a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

  # several 'node' statements
  node [shape = box,
        fontname = Helvetica]
  A; B; C; D; E; F

  node [shape = circle,
        fixedsize = true,
        width = 0.9] // sets as circles
  1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8

  # several 'edge' statements
  A->1 B->2 B->3 B->4 C->A
  1->D E->A 2->4 1->5 1->F
  E->6 4->6 5->7 6->7 3->8
}
")

pDia
```

[image]

Therefore, I would like to combine plots like `pDia`, class `"grViz" "htmlwidget"`, into a single image with labels such `A`, `B` and so on. I tried to export a svg file of the plot with the `exportSVG` function. Thus, would be possible to use the `magick` package to import and deal with different plots of such a class (i.e. `"grViz" "htmlwidget"`). However, this function is not available in the newer version of the `DiagrammeR` package. Any ideas to combine these plots in a figure that could be exported to a figure file such as `pdf` or `tiff`?

Comment: For the graphs to be combined, are you able to define them in one dag call or are they rendered separately and you want to combine the resultant pdfs? If you are happy for pdf (or png or tiff ...etc ) output why not skip diagrammer and just use graphviz?

Comment: I want to combine different diagrams in just one figure. In the same way `cowplot` does with  ggplots.

Comment: okay, thanks. And given you mention pdf & tiff am I correct in that you do not need the html tools / interactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps one of the following approaches will suit your needs.

1. You can add additional/disconnected graphs by just adding them to the same `digraph` call. For example, we can add two other graphs (U -> V -> W and X -> Y -> Z) to the right of your graph by just adding the nodes & edges after the other graph; you just need to make sure the nodes are named differently from the nodes in the preceding graphs. This can however, lead to large complicated scripts and may not suit your workflow.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
pDia <- grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {

  # your existing graph here

  # 2nd graph
  U -> V -> W;
  
  # 3rd graph
  X -> Y -> Z;
}")
```

[image]

2. Given that you are wanting a static output it is probably easier just to go straight to [`graphviz`](http://www.graphviz.org/). One way to combine graphs is by adding them as images to existing nodes. For example, if you have two graphs saved as png [(other formats)](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html):

```
cat(file="so-65040221.dot", 
" 
digraph boxes_and_circles {
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]
  node [shape = box, fontname = Helvetica]
  A; B; C; D; E; F
  node [shape = circle, fixedsize = true, width = 0.9] 
  1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8
  A->1 B->2 B->3 B->4 C->A
  1->D E->A 2->4 1->5 1->F
  E->6 4->6 5->7 6->7 3->8
}")

# This will write out two pngs. We will use these as examples for us to combine
system("dot -Tpng -Gdpi=300 so-65040221.dot -o so-65040221A.png -o so-65040221B.png")
```

Then create a new graph to read in the pngs and add them to the nodes

```
cat(file="so-65040221-combine.dot", 
'graph {
        node [shape=none]
        a [label="", image="so-65040221A.png"];
        b [label="", image="so-65040221B.png"];
}')
```

We execute this and output to pdf with

```
system("dot -Tpdf so-65040221-combine.dot > so-65040221-combine.pdf")
# or output tiff etc
# system("dot -Ttif so-65040221-combine.dot > so-65040221-combine.tiff")
```

[image]

You can then arrange multiple graphs by how you arrange the nodes in the combined script.

Comment: ... just another thought; after you have written a graph out to png (ot svg for that matter) you can then read it  into r and then combine using usual tools.

Comment: Hi user20650, can you please answer my question (shttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094669/how-to-change-the-font-size-color-and-style-while-setting-engine-htmlwidget) which is regarding htmlwidget? I have tried a lot. But failed.