# Plot two data.tree objects side by side

Tags: r, plot, htmlwidgets, data.tree

I am using the data.tree package to create some trees.

```
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)

acme <- Node$new("Acme Inc.")
accounting <- acme$AddChild("Accounting")
software <- accounting$AddChild("New Software")
standards <- accounting$AddChild("New Accounting Standards")


acme2 <- Node$new("Acme Inc. 2")
accounting2 <- acme2$AddChild("Accounting 2")
software2 <- accounting2$AddChild("New Software 2")
standards2 <- accounting2$AddChild("New Accounting Standards 2")


acme_plot <- plot(acme)
acme_plot2 <- plot(acme2)
```

[image]

I would like to put the two graphs next to each other in a grid. But as they are not `ggplot` objects (and I cannot convert them via `ggplotify`), I have failed with the following:

`cowplot`
`par(mfrow)`

I consulted this answer as well: [Combine different grViz into a single plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040221/combine-different-grviz-into-a-single-plot) but my trees are generated via a complex loop so I cannot generate them in the digraph boxes_and_circles call.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `manipulateWidget` with the function `combineWidgets`.

If you want them side by side, this works:

```
manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(plot(acme), plot(acme2), ncol = 2)
```

You won't be able to put the objects `acme_plot` or `acme_plot2` in that function; you have to enter the call that creates those objects.

[image]